# Solutions to $y^2 = x^3 + k$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

The equation $y^2 = x^3 + k$ for $k = (4n-1)^3 - 4m^2$, with $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and no prime number that p is congruent to 1 modulo 4 divids m, doesn't have any answer and its proof can be obtained by using quadratic reciprocity law.

Do you know answers of this equation for two or three different values of $k$? In addition, do you know any reference about that?

Comment: This question could sure use a little effort on the format aspect (sentence structure, LaTex, etc).

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but some passages were too unclear to attempt an edit. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: The abrupt mention of $p$ needs clarification.  Is $p$ supposed to be $k$, or a prime factor of $k$?

Comment: I wish more people knew what they were missing out on by not knowing how to TeX!

Comment: "As you know": that is not a good way to start, as many who read the question will *not* know.  I think "count $m$" is supposed to be "divides $m$."

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf See this paper. These are Mordell's equations and can also sometimes be solved using only elementary unique factorization in $\mathbb Z$ or sometimes by using the UFDs $\mathbb Z\left[\sqrt{-1}\right]$, $\mathbb Z\left[\sqrt{-2}\right]$.

Answer (score 6):

This is a famous class of elliptic curves, called [Mordell's equation](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2008/mordell.pdf), or sometimes Mordell-Bachet equation. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023139/what-is-stopping-every-mordell-equation-from-having-a-truly-elementary-proof), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001803/how-many-duplication-formulas-exist-for-the-mordell-curve-family-y2-x3-c) for some discussions on MSE. For a specific example with $k=2000000$ see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450775/how-find-all-positive-a3-b22000000/451120#451120). A further reference is [this article](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) by Keith Conrad.