# Solving a diophantine equation in an elementary way

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was trying to solve $x^2+1=y^3$ and found this answer: [Does an elementary solution exist to $x^2+1=y^3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955967/does-an-elementary-solution-exist-to-x21-y3/956182#956182)

but I'm having trouble understanding it.

In the second last paragraph, why is there a contradiction ($\textrm{mod}\  49$) ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is Mordell's equation. For elementary solutions, see [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf). See also the references [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107144/solutions-to-y2-x3-k?rq=1).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde I know what mordell equation is but I'm specifically interested in Slade's solution.

Comment: I see - you can ask him perhaps (with a comment below his answer).

Comment: I read this question and spent some time reading Slade's answer, and I couldn't get it either. I've dropped him a comment.

Comment: @shardulc Thanks a lot! I hope he could fix his answer because I really like his solution.

Comment: Stan Dolan contributed a really lovely — and completely elementary — solution on the linked post.