# Equations system question

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations

I have a problem said that : solve in $ \mathbb{Z} $ the equation  $$ y^{2}+ x^{3}= 9 $$ I tried this way.  $ y^{2}+ x^{3}= 9 \iff y= \pm \sqrt{9-x^2} $
Then $9-x^{2} \geq 0 $ so we get $(3, 0) $ and $ x^{3}=(y-3)(y+3) $ and get $(0, 3)\& (0, -3) $.  My question is how I can get the other pairs that satisfy this equation?.  Thanks

Comment: Well, and $(x,y)=(2,\pm1)$.

Comment: @MikeBennett yes this two pairs satisfy this equation.  How we get them?

Comment: check my answer, i get another solution.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz nice solution thanks.  I will study  it carefully

Comment: By the way if my answer satisfies what you seek, don't forget to choose as accepted

Comment: This is a Bachet-Mordell equation; for references see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107144/solutions-to-y2-x3-k?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I get another solution $(-3,6)$. I don't know how many solution there are, but if i found more i will edit this post. Here is my approach:

If **$x\geq0$** then we have $0\geq x\geq2.08$ since $y^2 \geq 0$ must be satisfied. Then by trial and error, we substitute $x=0, x=1, x=2$ one by one to see if there is corresponding $y$. In which **we get the solutions you already gave**, namely $(0,3)$ and $(0,-3)$ **and two others** $(2,-1)$ and $(2,1)$.

Now let us change our focus on next condition, **where we assume $x<0$**. Here we have $y^{2}= 9 - x^{3}$. Here there may be solutions for some (x,y) since $y^2\geq 0 $ is satisfied.

Now for simplicity, i will change the equation by letting $x=-x$, then we have $y^{2}= 9 + x^{3}$, for $x > 0 $. Carry constant 9 to other side, then we have $y^{2}- 9 = x^{3}$ which implies $(y-3)(y+3) = x^{3}$. Now i assumed that i can find a solution such that $$(y-3)^2=(y+3)$$ which could gave us the number we seek. Namely if such $y$ exist we have $(y-3)^3= x^3$. Solving the equation $$(y-3)^2=(y+3)$$ we find $y=6$, and $y=1$. Substituting back in the equations we get solutions $(-3,6)$ and $(2,1)$. But $|y|\geq 3$ and $x < 0 $ must be satisfied , then we find only one solution which is$$(-3,6)$$

Comment: Thousands of typos corrected

Comment: explain that please

Comment: exactly what point you didn't understand?

Comment: sir you say above that there is thousands of pairs correct that satisfy the equation.  I hope that you explain that?

Comment: There were some typos. For instance, there was written $(6,-3)$ for solution in which i mean $x=-3$ and $y=6$. But (6,-3) does not implies $x=-3$ and $y=6$. Rather it implies that $x=6$ and $y=-3$, so i corrected it and write $(−3,6)$. Things like that. My brain plays similar games a lot to me. What i thought and what i write may become different sometimes. Things like that. Now the solution is corrected, there should not be any problem now.